# sales_order_payment_place_end not working?

Tags: magento2

Why is my custom `sales_order_payment_place_end` event not working.

If i enable this in my events.xml I cannot place the order.

**Page redirects from:**

Checkout/cart/ -> Payment page -> mini cart page. (Does not go to success page).

If i comment out the below it works fine!!

Has any1 faced the similar problem for this event?

**My events.xml**

```
<event name="sales_order_payment_place_end">
    <observer name="sales_order_payment_place_end_handler" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\SyncProductPaymentComplete"/>
</event>
```

What is the problem here.

The error in browser console:

[image]

```
 function makeError(id, msg, err, requireModules) {
    var e = new Error(msg + '\nhttp://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#' + id);
    e.requireType = id;
    e.requireModules = requireModules;
    if (err) {
        e.originalError = err;
    }
    return e;
}
```