# Place order not going to checkout success Magento2

Tags: magento2, checkout, cart

Why is my payment page redirecting from

`checkout/#payment` to `checkout/cart/`?

[image]

[image]

Comment: please stop posting the same question again.

Comment: Its not duplicate @Marius, In http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/132749/sales-order-payment-place-end-not-working, there is an issue with event..Current question issue is happening for the same event in Place order time

Comment: Issue is with fresh instance of magento